# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'applications'

Tags: python, keras

Trying to convert a keras model (Thumbs.h5) into an onnx model on Google Colab, however I am getting an "AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'applications'" error when I run the code.

My code:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model
import onnx
import keras2onnx

onnx_model_name = 'fish-resnet50.onnx'

model = load_model('model-resnet50-final.h5')
onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert_keras(model, model.name)
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, onnx_model_name)
```

What I've tried:

- Updating keras with !pip install keras --upgrade (already updated)
- Running it locally with a jupyter notebook on my M1 Mac (V12.4) to get the same error

Pointers or solutions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved by specifying path to the entire folder rather than the .h5 file!

Comment: What? How could that solve the issue, doesn't the error trigger when you `import keras2onnx`?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation

> keras2onnx has been tested on Python 3.5 - 3.8, with tensorflow
> 1.x/2.0 - 2.2

So install compatible version of tensorflow.
Also keras-onnx is not under active development so use [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx) as per the documentation